Clarification on the $T$, and $CP$ Violation of the Weinberg Three-Gluon Operator
The Weinberg three-gluon operator is given by [https://inspirehep.net/literature/26600] $$\mathcal{O} = - \frac{1}{6} C f_{abc} G_{a\mu\rho} G_{b\nu}{}^{\rho} G_{c \lambda \sigma} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda \sigma} = - \frac{1}{3} C f_{abc} G_{a\mu\rho} G_{b\nu}{}^{\rho} \tilde{G}_{c}^{\mu \nu}$$
Weinberg claims that this operator violates $P$ and $T$ (and thus $CP$ by $CPT$ theorem). However I don't understand the claim of $T$-violating.
Analysis of Parity Violation
Under $P$ symmetry, the gluon field strength should transform as $G^{a}_{\mu \nu} \xrightarrow{P} \mathscr{P}_{\mu}^{\mu'} \mathscr{P}_{\nu}^{\nu'} G^{a}_{\mu' \nu'}$ with $\mathscr{P} = \mathrm{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$.
Therefore $\mathcal{O}$ violates parity:
$$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{P} - \frac{1}{6} C f_{abc} (\mathscr{P}_{\mu}^{\mu'}\mathscr{P}_{\rho}^{\rho'}G_{a\mu'\rho'}) (\mathscr{P}_{\nu}^{\nu'}\mathscr{P}^{\rho}_{\rho''}G_{b\nu'}{}^{\rho''}) (\mathscr{P}_{\lambda}^{\lambda'}\mathscr{P}_{\sigma}^{\sigma'}G_{c \lambda' \sigma'}) \epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda \sigma}
= - \mathcal{O}$$
where I use the facts that $\mathscr{P}_{\rho}^{\rho'}\mathscr{P}^{\rho}_{\rho''} = \delta^{\rho'}_{\rho''}$ and $\mathscr{P}_{\mu}^{\mu'}\mathscr{P}_{\nu}^{\nu'}\mathscr{P}_{\lambda}^{\lambda'}\mathscr{P}_{\sigma}^{\sigma'}\epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda \sigma} = -\epsilon^{\mu' \nu' \lambda' \sigma'}$
Ok, up to here I agree with Weinberg's claims.
Concerns Regarding Charge Conjugation and $CP$ Violation
However if now we look at charge conjugation, we should have the transformation $G^{a}_{\mu \nu} \xrightarrow{C} -G^{a}_{\mu \nu}$, which means that
$$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{C} -\mathcal{O}$$
and threfore
$$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{CP} \mathcal{O}$$
contrary to the claims from Weinberg.
I also get the same result by inspecting the $T$ symmetry directly, using $G^{a}_{\mu \nu} \xrightarrow{T} - \mathscr{P}_{\mu}^{\mu'} \mathscr{P}_{\nu}^{\nu'} G^{a}_{\mu' \nu'}$ we can redo exactly the same calculation to obtain
$$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{T} \mathcal{O}$$
Where am I wrong? Clearly Weinberg is not the only one claiming that $\mathcal{O}$ violates CP, there are a lot of similar articles doing the same claim, however I don't find anyone justifying it.
Could someone help me find the mistake? Is there an error in the transformation properties of the fields?

I found the problem in my reasoning. The charge conjugation of the gluon field is given by
$$G^a_{\mu\nu} = - C^{ab} G^b_{\mu\nu}$$
with $C^{ab}$ a symmetric matrix defined by $T^a_{ij} C^{ab} = T^b_{ji}$, with $T$ the generators of su(3). In particular this means that the structure constants $f^{abc}$ have the following property:
$$f^{abc}C^{aa'}C^{bb'}C^{cc'} = -2i (T^a_{ij}T^b_{jk}T^c_{ki} - T^a_{ij}T^c_{jk}T^b_{ki})C^{aa'}C^{bb'}C^{cc'} = -2i (T^{a'}_{ji}T^{b'}_{kj}T^{c'}_{ik} - T^{a'}_{ji}T^{c'}_{kj}T^{b'}_{ik}) = -2i (T^{a'}_{ji}T^{c'}_{ik}T^{b'}_{kj} - T^{a'}_{ji}T^{b'}_{ik}T^{c'}_{kj}) = -f^{a'b'c'}$$
Thus, the Weinberg operator transforms under $C$ as
$$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{C} - \frac{1}{3} C f_{abc} (-C_{aa'}G_{a'\mu\rho}) (-C_{bb'}G_{b'\nu}{}^{\rho}) (-C_{cc'}\tilde{G}_{c'}^{\mu \nu}) = - \frac{1}{3} C (-C_{aa'}C_{bb'}C_{cc'}f_{abc}) G_{a'\mu\rho} G_{b'\nu}{}^{\rho} \tilde{G}_{c'}^{\mu \nu} = - \frac{1}{3} C f_{a'b'c'} G_{a'\mu\rho} G_{b'\nu}{}^{\rho} \tilde{G}_{c'}^{\mu \nu} = \mathcal{O}$$
which thus gives a $CP$-violating operator, as claimed.
